# How do I create a pop-up on plotly express treemap (python)h

Tags: plotly, plotly-python, plotly-express

I am creating a treemap using plotly express & python. Objective is to export as HTML and embed in another webpage.

I am trying to disable zoom, i.e when I click on a tile it zooms in, instead of that behavior I want to keep the the size same (no changes) but create a pop-up with information about the tile. Example: https://whalewisdom.com/report/heat_map

I could use hoover, but hoover doesn't work on mobile sites. I tried every trick that I can find but not working :(

Any pointers ?

What I tried:staticPlot=True, scrollZoom=False,dragMode=False settings. Tried to add it to go.Fig but same effect. I could not disable zoom on click. And I could not find documentation on how to add event to pass to a javascript so that I can create a pop-up

Comment: "*I tried every trick that I can find but not working*": can you please summarize what tricks you've tried and *how* they didn't work? That ensures that nobody spends time on an answer that contains a method you already tried and didn't work for your case.

Comment: Additionally, could you include an [mcve]?